# React.js built website not showing source code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a website built with React.js, where if I right click and click on view page source option, I can't see the code of the website. Is it ok if the code is not shown for SEO?  It shows this much only.

I right click and clicked on view page source but couldn't find the code like any other website

Answer (score 0):

Any website you develop using react or similar framework ,it is always rendered as plain html/js to the web browser, so your react code would have been re-rendered into js which you dont recognise , if you want to check your components structure or the props you pass you can use React Developer Tools like @Fulya suggested